backwards and richardson differences in rust with ndarray
I'm trying to implement backwards differences (which use the current and previous data point) and Richardson differences (which use the next two and previous two data points). Forward differences (which use the current and next data point can be implemented by:
use ndarray as nd;

let forward_difference = nd::Array::from_iter(
        x_values
            .windows(2)
            .into_iter()
            .map(|x| forwards_difference(x[0], x[1], stepsize)),
    );

where forward_difference is a function which calculates the forward difference. However when using windows the first window contains the 0th to nth values in the array e.g. the first window of test.window(3) contains test[0], test[1], test[2] whereas I will need previous points for backwards and Richardson differences. e.g. the second richardson difference point needs the 0th, 1st 3rd and 4th data points.
Currently the best way I can think of to do this is to chain the iterators producing backwards/richardson differences to an iterator producing an appropriate placeholder value. Thereby introducing an appropriate offset (one placeholder value for backwards differences and two for Richardson). Is there a better way to do this? Thanks,

I don't understand the problem. If you need the 0th, 1st, 3rd and 4th data points, just use .windows (5) and ignore x[2]

The problem is not ignoring x[2] it's the offset required, as the first value that can be produced will be the richardson difference centered on test[2]
